# Image not showing on preloaded UIImageView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview, lazy-loading

When app launches I add UIImageViews to screen with no image. Then I load image one by one using `NSThread` and set it for those views. The UiImageViews remain blank until after all images have been loaded and the thread finishes. Why doesn't the image show as soon as I set it for the `UIImageView`, why does it wait for `NSThread` to end?

To add image views :

```
for(i = value; i < val; i++){
    UIButton *newbutton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    [newbutton setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
    UIImageView *newback = [[UIImageView alloc] init];
    newback.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
    [newback setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 140, 140)];
    [newbutton addSubview:newback];
    height = MIN(300, newSize.height);
    [newbutton setFrame:CGRectMake(currentX, currentY, width, height)];
    newbutton.layer.cornerRadius = 10;
    newbutton.clipsToBounds = YES;
    [newbutton addTarget:self action:@selector(processButtonClick:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
}
```

To add images in a thread I call a function which does following :

```
for(i = value; i < val; i++){
    UIImage *newimage = [UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL    URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@“http://test.com/a.jpg”, hash]]]];
    UIButton *newbutton = (UIButton*)[self.subviews objectAtIndex:i];
    [((UIImageView*)[newbutton.subviews objectAtIndex:0]) newimage];
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't `[((UIImageView*)[newbutton.subviews objectAtIndex:0]) newimage];` be `[((UIImageView*)[newbutton.subviews objectAtIndex:0]) setImage:newimage];`

Comment: You shouldn't be messing with UIKit objects on background threads. Set the images on the main thread.

Comment: Roshan it is setImage I messed up while copying. Eric if I do it on the main thread, the application is in a hung state till is finished loading all the images. How do I load one image and display it at a time while not making the interaction hung?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally speaking, `UIKit` is not thread-safe. Fetch data from URL in a background thread and set the image in the main thread.

EDIT: 
In your main thread do something like

```
dispatch_async(someDispatchQ, ^{
    [self functionToGetData];
});
```

and inside `functionToGetData` do

```
for(i = value; i < val; i++){
    NSData *data = //get Data
    UIImage *newImage = //make image from data
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        [imageView setImage:newImage];
    });
}
```

This will ensure that you are using a background thread to fetch data/make image and using the main thread to set the image. This also eliminates the need to use a timer to constantly poll the background thread since the background thread automatically dispatches image-setting to the main thread as soon as an image is received.

Answer (score 0):

use- 
**import class ImageDownloader.h & .m**
link-> https://github.com/psychs/imagestore/tree/master/Classes/Libraries/ImageStore

**//Now use this method to download**

```
-(void)downloadImageWithURL:(NSString *)url{


    if(self.downloder)return; //If already downloading please stay away

    url=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%0.0fx%0.0f/%@/%@",IMAGE_ENDPOINT,self.imgViewExhibitors.frame.size.width,self.imgViewExhibitors.frame.size.height,@"fit",[ImagePath forURLString:url]];

    self.downloder=[[ImageDownloader alloc] init];
    self.downloder.delegate=self;
    self.downloder.indicator=self.indicator;
    [self.downloder downloadImageWithURL:url];
}

-(void)imageDownloaded:(UIImage *)image forIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    if(image){
        //Put the downloaded image in dictionary to update while scrolling
        //[self.speakerData setObject:image forKey:@"image"];
        self.imgViewExhibitors.image=image;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple fix would be

```
for(i = value; i < val; i++){
    UIImage *newimage = [UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL    URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@“http://test.com/a.jpg”, hash]]]];
    UIButton *newbutton = (UIButton*)[self.subviews objectAtIndex:i];

    // this ensures that the UI update (setting the image) is done on the main thread.
    // This is important for the UI to update properly.
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
         [((UIImageView*)[newbutton.subviews objectAtIndex:0]) setImage:newimage];
    }
}
```